# Split column in asp:DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, split

Should hopefully be pretty simple.  I have a column in my datagrid that has emails for notification.  They are separated by a ';'.  I want to put a `"<br>"` after each ';' so that the grid doesn't expand too far off of the page.  I was able to get a function going that allowed me to see each row before it was created, but when I was trying to retrieve the value to edit it, it was returning null.  I'm going to try and retrieve that function as I erased it on Friday, but was wondering if someone had any links or examples on how to do this.

I have:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |                    Notify                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   | email1@emailserver.com;email2@emailserver.com |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |          Notify         |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   | email1@emailserver.com; |
|         |         |         | email2@emailserver.com  |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that I was using the ItemCreated function and trying to retrieve the values from the DataGridItemEventArgs.  Working on the function now.

#### Update

Ok, so I got back to this as a test:

```
Private Sub ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.ItemCreated
    If e.Item.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Dim int As Integer = 0  'I put a breakpoint here to evalute the information
    End If
End Sub
```

When I hit the breakpoint the first time, the .Text attribute shows that it is Notification which is exactly what it's supposed to be as the header field.  On the next break, and subsequent breaks, the .Text attribute is "".  Now, this grid is databound on Page_Load, but would that affect this?  Wouldn't the value have to be in the DataGridItemEventArgs for that record to be created?  I know when I ViewSource of the page when I'm done it shows the information there, but I don't know if that could be set after the table is drawn, but I doubt it.  Any help would highly be appreciated.  Thanks.  Here's the Page_Load and BindData functions just incase you need them.

#### Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        BindData("")
    End If
End Sub
```

#### BindData

```
Private Sub BindData(ByVal strSort As String)
    Dim tsDS As CustomDataSet = New CustomDataSet
    For Each dr As DataRow In tsDS.GetData("").Tables(0).Rows
        If dr.Item(2).ToString().StartsWith("Vacancy") Then
            dr.Delete()
        End If
    Next
    Dim dv As DataView = tsDS.GetData("").Tables(0).DefaultView

    If strSort.Length > 0 Then
       dv.Sort = strSort
    End If
    dgTasks.DataSource = dv
    dgTasks.DataBind()
End Sub
```

#### Here's what I get on the first Item row.

[image]

#### Update: Fix

```
Protected Sub Item_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim notification As String = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row, Utilities.CustomDS.Row).Notification
            e.Item.Cells(7).Text = "<a href=""mailto:" & notification & """>" & notification.Replace(";", ";<br>") & "</a>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want the `ItemDataBound` event. `ItemCreated` is when that row of the `DataGrid` is created.  The controls are there, but that’s it.  On the `ItemDataBound` event, the controls are bound to their data, and the data is available for access.  If you have logic that depends on the bound data, use the `ItemDataBound` event, which fires after the `ItemCreated` event.

You wire that up in the .aspx code by assigning the event handler name to the event, such as

```
OnItemDataBound = "MyDataGrid_ItemDataBound"
```

Within that event, you start by examining the type of item you are looking at.

Then, you find the cell and control. And finally, you set the Text property to your altered text.

Here is an example:

```
protected void MyDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
       e.Item.Cells[3].Text == <assign your altered text here>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, well this seems to act the same as ItemCreated as it shows me the same information for .Text, nothing.  What I wanted to do was get the information that was about to be written, "email1@emailserver.com;email2@emailserver.com", and then edit it by adding a <br> after the ;, but I do not see the value anywhere even though I know there is a value in the first row returned.  Am I going to have to edit the dataset?

Comment: Trying to look up the info on this function now, maybe I shouldn't be looking at .Text.

Comment: You assign a value to Text. You obtain the data from DataItem, which is the data source you are binding the control to. You can see it in ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString(); -- there are a lot of ways to do this, but you need to get the DataItem, get the incoming text from there, do your substitution of a line break, and then set the resulting string to the Text property.

Comment: Ok, well the column that it's going into is a HyperlinkColumn.  Should this still work?  I'm about to try it, but if you can think of any reason why it wouldn't, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it kind of works, but I do think it affects the Hyperlink column.  It breaks the link, but the hyperlinks are now gone.  I'm guessing that this happens before the item is written, meaning it then takes the text and uses it in my mailto:.

Comment: Changed the column to a BoundColumn, and just added the mailto link myself before editing the text.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm so glad you worked it out. It isn't a simple thing that you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't figure it was, but rather than having someone scroll left to right to be able to view the whole grid, I wanted to shorten it up without making the font too small.